# Animated particles python

Tags: python, animation, tkinter, graph, updates

I have to write a script that simulates gas particles in a cube

The problem is that graph doesn't update as I want

Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Canvas,Button,Tk
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

c_cube   = input("Donnez le côté de l'enceinte (cm) :")
n_part   = input("Donnez le nombre de particules :")
dt       = input("Donnez l'intervale de temps δt de déplacement (ms) :")
module_v = input("Donnez la vitesse initiale (module) :")
m_part   = input("Donnez la masse des particules (g) :")

pression = 0
volume   = int(c_cube)**3
surface  = (int(c_cube)**2)
temps    = 0.0 

x = np.random.uniform(0,int(c_cube),int(n_part))
y = np.random.uniform(0,int(c_cube),int(n_part))
z = np.random.uniform(0,int(c_cube),int(n_part))

teta    = np.random.uniform(0,2*np.pi,int(n_part))
sin_teta= np.sin(teta)
cos_teta= np.cos(teta)
phi     = np.random.uniform(0,2*np.pi,int(n_part))
sin_phi = np.sin(phi)
cos_phi = np.cos(phi)

vx = int(module_v)*sin_teta*cos_phi
vy = int(module_v)*sin_teta*sin_phi
vz = int(module_v)*cos_teta

dx = vx*float(dt)
dy = vy*float(dt)
dz = vz*float(dt)

def new_coordinates() :  
    global x
    x = np.where(x >  float(c_cube),x-dx,x)
    x = np.where(x <= float(c_cube),x+dx,x)
    global y
    y = np.where(y >  float(c_cube),y-dy,y)
    y = np.where(y <= float(c_cube),y+dy,y)
    global z
    z = np.where(z >  float(c_cube),z-dz,z)
    z = np.where(z <= float(c_cube),z+dz,z)
    global temps
    temps += float(dt)
    return x,y,z
```

Here the graph is updateted

```
def update_graph(inc):
    new_coordinates()
    print(x,y,z,c_cube) # here I print the new coordinates to verify if they are changed
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.axes.xaxis.set_ticks([])
    ax1.axes.yaxis.set_ticks([])
    ax1.axes.zaxis.set_ticks([])
    ax1.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', depthshade=False, marker='o')

fenetre_simulation = tk.Tk()                                               
fenetre_simulation.title("Simulation Gaz parfait")  
fenetre_simulation.configure(background="grey")     

fig1 = Figure(figsize=(8, 5), dpi=112)            
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

graph_particules = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=fenetre_simulation)
tk.canvas = graph_particules.get_tk_widget()
tk.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(fenetre_simulation, text='Quitter', width=10,height=2,
          command=fenetre_simulation.destroy).grid(column=2,row=1)

animation_particules = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_graph, interval=800)

#x,y,z = new_coordinates(x,y,z)

fenetre_simulation.mainloop()
```

You can simulate with the inputs : 5 , 1 (for 1 particle) , 0.1 , 2, 1
and you will see at the console the print(x,y,z,c_cube) with new values
but the grapf doesn't change.... Why??????

(PS : to make it work, please join the 2 blocks of code)